# How's this inertia called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, field-theory, terminology

Let $E/F$ be an algebraic extension.

Let $L_1,L_2$ be algebraically closed fields and $\sigma_1:F\rightarrow L_1,\sigma_2:F\rightarrow L_2$ be field monomorphisms.

Define $A=\{\tau_1|\tau_1:E\rightarrow L_1 \text{ is a field monomorphism and an extension of } \sigma_1\}$

Define $B=\{\tau_2|\tau_2:E\rightarrow L_2 \text{ is a field monomorphism and an extension of } \sigma_2\}$.

Then, it can be shown that $|A|=|B|$.

Hence, it's possible to define this cardinality as ${E:F}$ when an algebraic extension $E/F$ is given.

What is the **name** of ${E:F}$? And how is it called? Is there an article about this number in wikipedia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the value you are asking about is the $\textbf{separable degree}$.

Read the comments and answers at [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142979/definition-of-separability-degree) for more information. This is a very important concept in field theory.